# Network programming Language can been done in which of the following languages a)C b)C++ c)Java d)pascal

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

This question was asked in multiple choice question in an interview.

Network programming can be done in which of the following languages?

a) C
b) C++
c) Java
d) Pascal

I think it is possible to network programming in each of these technology.

Comment: There is nothing in those language to prevent such a thing, so there is no reason to suspect it cannot be done using a library.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety#Type_safety_issues_in_specific_languages doesn't agree with you

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis I agree that C++ is not a Toy. ;)

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis I would think that if Java was a Toy, more people would like it. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Indeed all of them (just perhaps Pascal is not a good choice), just take a look at these books :

[Network Programming in C](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Network-Programming-C-Barry-Nance/dp/0880225696)

[C++ Network Programming, Volume I: Mastering Complexity with ACE and Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201604647)

[Java Network Programming, Third Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007213)

A question with resources available on SO:
[Sockets in pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054/sockets-in-pascal)

Comment: @PeterLawrey> Yes, always dear google :) And obviously all these books are not for nothing!

Answer (score 2):

Any one of these languages can be used for network programming. And more generally, I think you'd struggle to find any (non-esoteric) programming language that doesn't offer any kind of support for network I/O.